# Comma when translating a single word e.g. "A gato ("cat" in Spanish) is a fluffy feline."

Tags: commas, translation

Would you put a comma in there? And why?

1. A gato ("cat" in Spanish) is a fluffy feline.
2. A gato ("cat," in Spanish) is a fluffy feline.
3. A gato ("cat", in Spanish) is a fluffy feline.

Thank you for any insight!

(Please ignore the clumsy example.)

Comment: Answers go in the answer box, not the comment box. This question has been locked against further comments because answers were being inappropriately given by community members in comments that are now deleted.

Answer (score 2):

*Un gato*, a cat in Spanish, is a fluffy feline.

I would make it an appositive. There is no need for parenthesis in this example.

Maybe more complex ones might need parenthesis as, for example, in the translation of legal concepts, literary studies or philosophy.

Comment: Just to spell it out, there's no need for the comma either.

Comment: @KateBunting Appositives are always set off by commas, So, there is a need for two commas in this case. A cat in Spanish is **un gato**.

Comment: You could also put single quotes around 'a cat' to note that the cat is not Spanish-speaking.

Comment: @JohnLawler Did you see the video on the BBC of the NY lawyer and his **three cats** in foreign lands? It's under videos of the day. I just don't understand your comment. Sorry.

Comment: Alas, I don't watch videos. Saves me enormous time for reading.

Comment: I meant the one which the OP had put after _cat_, not the ones you have used instead of brackets.

Comment: Sorry but the BBC news site is full of exciting reading but some of their videos are worth it.

Comment: @KateBunting I see. How's a body to tell? This is the problem with systematic deletion of comments.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, this has been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to comment on the " A gato". It's " Un Gato, meaning one Cat, or " O Gato, meaning the Cat."
Then there's " A gata, the female Cat."
That's was the only point, I wanted to make.
Thank you for the subject, in question, I like the point, that's why, I came here.

Comment: Answers should only be used to directly answer the question. If you want to challenge the premise of a question or the details, you should use the comments under the question. This option will become available when you gain the necessary reputation by asking and/or answering questions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This would be Portuguese, correct?

Comment: @user458280 No, Portuguese uses **um and uma**.